# What's the difference between :update and :w in Vim?

Tags: vim

I realized that in gvim `Control+S` as the `:update` command. I always save using `Ctrl+S`, so I assume that `:update` is another way of saying "refresh the changes." Is `:update` basically the same as write `:w`? Will I have problems if I replace `:update` for `:w!`?

**edit: I wanted to change `:update` to `:w!` becauase I have a file that says "ready-only please add `!`." And I thought this was the only solution**

Comment: You can use bang (`!`) with update command.

Answer (score 26):

Here is another way to explain the difference between `:write` (shortcut `:w`) and `:update` (shortcut `:up`) :

Whenever we type `:w`, VIM will literally write the buffer to the file, no matter the buffer is empty or not. That **MEANs** it will update the **timestamp** of the file to the time `:w` typed , even if the contents of the file did NOT actually changed.

While with `:up`, just like the *vim help manual* says, the VIM will ONLY update the **timestamp** when the file has been changed.

---

For example, when I open a file just for reading, but I may accidentally (or, habitually) type `:w` or `:wq`, and if I do care about the timestamps of the file (i.e. last modified time), then there's no turning back. The following examples (in BASH shell) show the effects:

```
$ touch test.txt
$
$ stat test.txt
      File: `test.txt'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828498    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-15 22:30:52.159258193 +0800
Modify: 2014-03-15 22:30:52.159258193 +0800
Change: 2014-03-15 22:30:52.159258193 +0800
```

---

Now let's VIM the file and try `:up` and `:w` command respectively:

```
$ vim test.txt
```

Do not editing, just type **`:up`** and then `:q`

```
$ stat test.txt
  File: `test.txt'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828498    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-15 22:33:10.002269244 +0800  <--- Different!
Modify: 2014-03-15 22:30:52.159258193 +0800  <--- Didn't Change!
Change: 2014-03-15 22:30:52.159258193 +0800  <--- Didn't Change!
```

As you can see, only the Access time is changed, this is because we read(Access) the data in the file. But the Modify time & Change time are still the same.

---

Now let's vim again and use the **`:w`** command.

```
$ vim test.txt
```

Do not editing, BUT this time type **`:w`** and then `:q`

```
$ stat test.txt
  File: `test.txt'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 811h/2065d  Inode: 98828538    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (  514/    rank)   Gid: (  514/    rank)
Access: 2014-03-15 22:40:26.728239153 +0800  <--- Different Again!
Modify: 2014-03-15 22:40:26.728239153 +0800  <--- Changed!
Change: 2014-03-15 22:40:26.728239153 +0800  <--- Changed!
```

Now we can see the difference between `:up` and `:w`! The data of the file is Modified and the file status also Changed, although there is nothing *really* changed in the file.

---

So to avoid this, one can map the `:w` command to the `:up` command using `:map :w :up`.

Comment: Is there a use case for `:up` that can't be achieved from just using `:q`? Because you can also  vim into a file and avoid changing the modify/change values by exiting with `:q`, assuming you VIM the file just for reading and don't make any changes.

Answer (score 19):

`:help :update` is pretty clear on that:

```
Like ":write", but only write when the buffer has been modified.
```

So the file will only written if the contents of the buffer have actually been changed. So if you use `:update` (or press Ctrl+S in GVim) and there are no unsaved changes in the buffer, it won't do anything.

Comment: I keep forgetting to use `:help`, and end up on StackOverflow. Emphasizing it in this answer was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

From the help:

```
:[range]up[date][!] [++opt] [>>] [file]
                        Like ":write", but only write when the buffer has been
                        modified.  {not in Vi}
```

Answer (score 2):

`:help :update` says:

> Like ":write", but only write when the buffer has been modified.